# Running same python from two different cores

Tags: python, python-3.x, cluster-computing

Is there a problem in running a python script from two different processes on separate cores on a cluster.
 The script resides in a global folder (accesable by both processes):

```
/cluster/A.py
```

I am concerned about the pycache and other stuff python writes...?
Do both cores have problems in generating the same pycache in folder /cluster/
Can I safely do this or are there some issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there should be no problems. The `__pycache__` folder only store compiled version of the code. So if the code does not change, you can run multiple python instances in parallel without any issue.